# when data is changed in real time database(firebase) app crashes

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Its data structue]
it don't just do with this data , error is same with [image: this one too]
when i save data from other device into databse (firebase) app crashes where data is retrieved and set into recycle view in other device

onDataChange is realtime when data is changed it is automatically called
Notification Class

```
public class Notifications {
    private String Name;
    private String Email;
    private String Message;
    private String Time;
    private String Date;

    public Notifications() {

    }

    public Notifications(String Name, String Email, String Message, String Time, String Date) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Message = Message;
        this.Time = Time;
        this.Date = Date;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }
}
```

```
DatabaseReference userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notification");
        userref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    notificationList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Notifications notifications = userSnapshot.getValue(Notifications.class);

                        notificationList.add(notifications);

                    }
                    Collections.reverse(notificationList);
                    mAdapter = new Adapter_Notification(notificationList);
                    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

this error is shown

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type com.example.simpleapplocker.Notifications
```

at the line

```
 notificationList.add(notifications);
```

after start is retrieves that data and shows in recycle view 
it mean data exists or maybe notification is created but other data is not uploaded and this function is called maybe??

Comment: sir first check your notification model class attributes data types. and check your datachange respone . is it give you the object or boolean result.

Comment: According to your request from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883129/how-can-i-point-to-the-random-key-firebase-user-id/57885392#comment102253424_57885392), I will ask you now to add add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for being here i just added image here actually it works fine  when there is change in any notification  children but it crashes when new children is added  there is also a function setOnAddChildren but then it don't retrieves all notifications

Comment: @HasnainSabir i just updated question with image  you can have a look there is not boolean value

Comment: @MuhammadOwaisChaudhary Please also add the content of your `Notifications` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo have a look   i have hope you will solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

**Try this method, it worked for me**

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Notification");
                myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exist()) {
        Notifications notifications = userSnapshot.getValue(Notifications.class);
        
                                notificationList.add(notifications);
        
                            }
                            Collections.reverse(notificationList);
                            mAdapter = new 
      Adapter_Notification(notificationList);
                            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Notifications notifications = userSnapshot.getValue(Notifications.class);
```

In this line, you are getting the error that says Boolean object can't be converted to Notifications. This may appear if you have set the value of that child to true or false (Without double quotes). See it again and try to add a double quote around the "true" or "false" that you want to set to the child value.

Comment: then how it will get data of all notifications that exists

Comment: try this method and let me know if it works. this method will only call when app starts.

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also response

Comment: i just added image you can check

Comment: Use Firebase Recycleradapter. @MuhammadOwaisChaudhary