# Data not retrieving from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have a Firebase database as shown in the pic. I am trying to retrieve data based on some condition but it shows no results.

```
    DbRef2 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notification");

    DbRef2.child("45961").orderByChild("FromId").startAt("22222").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Notification notf = dataSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hai"+notf.getFromId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

There is nothing shows in the toast. I also tried equalTo instead of startAt. but  no results.

Comment: If you remove `startAt` AND `orderBy`? is there any value that you get?

Comment: yes....then it gives result

Comment: now add `orderbychild`, just make a work around if is not working , try add new notification with thesame ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four issues in your code. The first one would be the query that you are using. If you want to get the results based on a condition, please change the following query:

```
DbRef2.child("45961").orderByChild("FromId").startAt("22222").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

To:

```
DbRef2.orderByChild("FromId").startAt("22222").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

There is no need for a `.child("45961")` call, as you need to loop through the results.

The second issue is that you get the `DataSnapshot` object as an argument but you don't loop to get the results. To actually get the results you should use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Notification notf = ds.getValue(Notification.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hai"+notf.getFromId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The third issue is the fact that you are not checking for potential error. You also might consider using:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
}
```

The fourth issue lies in the fact that you are using names that start with an uppercase. For that, I recommend you see my answer from the following post:

> [Firebase Android ListView not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069574/firebase-android-listview-not-being-displayed)

Or:

> [how to read firestore sub-collection and pass it to FirestoreRecyclerOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924189/how-to-read-firestore-sub-collection-and-pass-it-to-firestorerecycleroptions/53943559#53943559)

If the fields in your class are lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 DbRef2.child("45961").orderByChild("FromId").startAt("22222").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

into this:

```
DbRef2.orderByChild("FromId").startAt("22222").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

If you want to use `FromId` inside `orderByChild()` then you don't need to access `child("45961")`

Comment: i tried it before it works but the result is null value. So i added that parent child(45961)